# Selected option colour override with class?

Tags: jquery, css, multi-select

I've tried to see this in other posts, but nothing is quite the same...

- HTML 5
- multiselect select

I have a multiselect with time slots that I stuff a class into specific options based on another multiselect's selected values.

See JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/devfingers/8bfmov6m/)

My jquery adds the class

```
$("#SelectedWedTimes").children('option').each(function (index, item) {
var val = $(this).val();
if ($.inArray(val, scheduledWedValues) > -1)
$(this).addClass('activeSchedule');
});
```

There are 4 slots with the class added, starting at 12:00 PM.
You can't see that because the selected state hides the option colour class

How can I get those to show through the 'selected' state?

The items that are 'scheduled' (12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, and 14:00), but are sort of hidden because of also being selected, should display with the darkblue class colour, and not the wacky hard to see blended colour.

Comment: Where do you want them to show?

Comment: @Laurence Fishburne I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Where the ListBox is rendered on screen, the items that are 'scheduled' (12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, and 14:00), but are sort of hidden because of *also* being selected, should display with the darkblue class colour, and not the wacky hard to see blended colour.